# In the Brackets text editor, what is the equivalent of Cntrl+D in Sublime Text?

Tags: brackets

In Sublime text, if I have multiple lines which contain the same thing, I can use the Cntrl+D shortcut key to select the next occurrence of the string my cursor is currently at, and also create a cursor there so that I can 'mass-edit' all the occurrences.

I'm trying to do the same now in Brackets, but I haven't been able to find anything in https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Working-with-Multiple-Selections. Is there such a feature in Brackets?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://blog.brackets.io/2014/04/15/brackets-0-38-release-multiple-cursors/?lang=en, what I'm looking for is Cntrl+B (to make multiple selections at a string).